# How to stringify Javascript function object with properties?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, stringify

In typescript, a class with static members is compiled into a function when each static member becomes a function object property.

**For example:**

```
class Config {
    static debug = true;
    static verbose = false;
}
```

**Becomes**

```
var Config = (function () {
    function Config() {
    }
    Config.debug = true;
    Config.verbose = false;
    return Config;
})();
```

Invoking `JSON.stringify` on such function object will result with `undefined`.
What is the right way to stringify in that case?

Comment: What output are you expecting? JSON cannot represent functions. Are you wanting to treat the function as if it were an object literal containing just its static members?

Comment: @JamesAllardice exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `JSON.stringify` does not take the functions. You could do it this way:

> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the [toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior) method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized.

An example:

```js
Function.prototype.toJSON = Function.prototype.toJSON || function(){
    var props = {};
    for(var x in this){
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(x)) props[x] = this[x]
    }
    return props
}

var Config = (function () {
    function Config() {
    }
    Config.debug = true;
    Config.verbose = false;
    return Config;
})();

console.log(JSON.stringify(Config))
```